# Operator '...' has the override specifier but does not override a base class member

Tags: c++, inheritance, abstract-class

I'm trying to inherit an abstract class and override all of its pure virtual functions

```
class A
{
    virtual bool operator==(const A&) const = 0;
}

class B : A
{
    bool operator==(const B& rhs) const override
    {                                   ^^^^^^^^---problem here
        // Comparison
    }
}
```

Error:

> Operator 'bool B::operator==(const B& rhs) const' has the 'override' specifier but does not override a base class member

Comment: and if you also have derived class C, what do you expect from `A&& a1 = B(); A&& a2 = C(); a1 == a2;`? Visitor pattern might help to have multiple dispatch.

Answer (score 2):

You can't override a `virtual` base class function when the signature differs. In `class B`, it must be

```
bool operator==(const A&) const override;
//                         ^^ must be reference to A
```

Note that testing runtime-polymorphic types for equality is always weird; you abstract away the type, then you try to compare two instances - but how is that supposed to happen, across derived types? Try to reserve `operator==` for classes that are intended to be used with value semantics.

Comment: So if B has some private members how can i access them if the parameter is of type A ?

Comment: You can't, except with some `dynamic_cast<B*>` hack. But I would try to avoid that. You're trying to implement a double dispatch on a small scale. The language doesn't give you that flexibility, and a visitor pattern would be quite an overkill I guess.

Comment: I can't understand why it isn't allowed in c++. If i want all class inheriting A to have an equality operator what should i do?

Comment: You could implement the operator as a non-`virtual` function. Then, you can't compare by `==` through static `A` instances, but as I said, this is confusing in the first place in my opinion.

Comment: What i want to achieve is to force people inheriting A to provide an equality operator, pure virtual functions has been designed for that, so why i can't use them in this scenario

Comment: Still, how it should work on two objects of different classes? What you _probably_ want is so called "concept", like here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/EqualityComparable It would be available in C++20.

Comment: @user7769147 It *is* allowed, however it's unadvisable, e.g. `class C : public B { bool operator==(const A&) const override; };` It's easy to get into a situation where `c == b` gives a different answer to `b == c`